# Restriction of the regular representation to a compact subgroup

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $H \subset G$ be a compact subgroup. If $n := [G:H] < \infty$, then we have $G = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^n g_i H$ for chosen representatives $g_1, \dots, g_n \in G$ and thus the underlying $H$-representation of the regular representation $\lambda_G = L^2(G)$ of $G$ decomposes as
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{res}^G_H\lambda_G = L^2(\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n g_iH) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^nL^2(H) = \bigoplus^{[G:H]}\lambda_H
\end{aligned}

**Question: What is the relation between $\operatorname{res}^G_H\lambda_G$ and $\lambda_H$ if $[G:H] = \infty$, i.e. if the dimension of $G$ is strictly larger than the dimension of $H$?**

For example, does $\lambda_H$ still embed into $\operatorname{res}^G_H\lambda_G$?

Comment: I would expect the same answer, but with a direct integral over $G/H$ instead of direct sum.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with direct integrals of representations. Can this still be compatible with the Peter-Weyl theorem that $\lambda_G$ is a direct sum $\bigoplus_{\pi \in \hat{G}} \oplus^{\dim \pi}\pi$?

Comment: Are you asking if the restriction of the regular rep being a direct integral would contradict the PW theorem? I don't see how it could.

Comment: Do you know an easy way to see that $\lambda_H$ embeds into $\operatorname{res}^G_H\lambda_G$?

Comment: I have no clue. I somehow expected that if it is some kind of 'integral' over many copies of $\lambda_H$, it would probably contain at least one copy of $\lambda_H$, but I guess this thinking was too naive.

Comment: Ideally you can pick a nice right transversal $T$ for $H\backslash G$, then take any $f\in L^2(H)$ and define a corresponding $\bar{f}\in L^2(G)$ by $\bar{f}(ht):=f(h)$ for all $t\in T,h\in H$.